# Dependency conflict in pentaho data integration when an external jar is called from UDJC step

Tags: spring, pentaho

I have a spring project which is deployed in libext folder in Pentaho Data Integration and called from "User Defined Java Class" step. I get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate` The project has a dependency on org.springframework.spring-jdbc (version 4.1.7) which has batchUpdate method in NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. However, the Pentaho lib folder has spring-2.5.6 jar which has org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate which probably doesn't have batchUpdate method. How can this dependency conflict be resolved..I have Pentaho CE 5.3.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to placing the jar file into /libext, you will also need to modify /launcher/launcher.properties to look for user defined libraries in libext. It will take effect on the next restart of Spoon.

```
libraries=../test:../lib:../libswt:../libext
classpath=../:../ui:../ui/images:../lib:../libext
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out @jarvis.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of R&D, I figured it was the problem with the version of spring jars used. Pentaho DI 5.3 has `org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` class in spring2.5.6 jar which doesn't have batchUpdate method. My project was built on spring 4 which has batchUpdate method in spring-jdbc jar. This was causing the dependency discrepancy and hence the `NoSuchMethodError`. I fixed it by using a later version of Pentaho DI (version 6.1) which internally uses Spring 3 and has no such conflicting jars.